# How to resize pixel of WriteableBitmap (windows store c#)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, writeablebitmap

I searched in many forums and I didn't get what I want.

My question is clear and simple : How to resize pixel of WriteableBitmap , for example from 300*300 to 500*500

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [WritableBitmapEx](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) project. You can use it or learn how to resize your image.
It is easy to do it by using `WritableBitmapEx` extensions methods.

```
// Resizes the WriteableBitmap to 200px wide and 300px high using a bilinear interpolation method
var resized = writeableBmp.Resize(200, 300, WriteableBitmapExtensions.Interpolation.Bilinear);
```